# Render graphical output in PTVS for visual studio with IPython REPL

Tags: python, visual-studio, ipython, ptvs

I am using IPython as the interactive prompt on PyTools for Visual Studio for 2013.

The inline rendering of charts/plots in the REPL is very low quality. Nowhere near the quality of notebook rendering in the browser.

If there some setting I am missing or anything I can do to improve this in PTVS.

PTVS version 2.0;  Python 2.7 32-bit;  Visual Studio 2013

Thanks.